# Display MKMapView Direction Path on top of regions/road names

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, mapkit

I need to display my path on top of the names of the regions/roads, so my path will be more visible. I don't want to do it with ZStack, maybe there are some request modifiers available?

Here is my code:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> MapViewCoordinator {
        return MapViewCoordinator()
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(
            center: .init(latitude: 40.71, longitude: -74),
            span: .init(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5))
        
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        
        let p1 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: .init(latitude: 40.71, longitude: -74))
        let p2 = MKPlacemark(coordinate: .init(latitude: 42.36, longitude: -71.05))
        
        let request = MKDirections.Request()
        request.source = MKMapItem(placemark: p1)
        request.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: p2)
        request.transportType = .walking
        
        let directions = MKDirections(request: request)
        directions.calculate { responce, error in
            guard let route = responce?.routes.first else { return }
            mapView.addAnnotations([p1,p2])
            mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline)
            mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, edgePadding: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 70, bottom: 20, right: 70), animated: true)
        }
        
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
    
    class MapViewCoordinator: NSObject, MKMapViewDelegate {
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
            let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(named: "darkGreen")
            renderer.lineWidth = 3
            renderer.lineCap = .round
            renderer.lineDashPattern = [10, 10]
            return renderer
        }
    }
}
```